# Need to include a link to the Salesforce Page where the Docusign request was sent from

Tags: docusignapi

We are sending contracts to be signed from within Salesforce to our Executive Team. We need an easy way for them to be able to identify and ideally click a link to take them to the Opportunity where the Docusign request originated from so they can see and verify the information

Answer (score 0):

If you know the SF Opp link then you can pass that link in an email body or as a Private Message in an envelope.